# What does it mean -r in catalina.sh?

Tags: bash, tomcat, catalina

In catalina.sh is row:

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/logging.properties ];
```

What does it mean -r ? Does it abbreviation? What other symbols can be?
Thanks.

Comment: test -r := file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for is in [`man test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/test.html):

> -r  pathname
>   True if pathname resolves to a file that exists and for which permission to read from the file will be granted, as defined in [File Read, Write, and Creation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_01_04). False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to a file for which permission to read from the file will not be granted.

Comment: You can also say `man [`, or `help [` if your `[` is a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html). -r means file has read permission.